# Travel Mode (walking, cycling, driving) Segmentation of GPS data in R

Tags: r, gps, classification, gis, geospatial

I work with GPS data (1 hz). I calculated the walking speed (meters per second) out of the coordinates information.
Now I have to **classify the typ of the travel mode:** Is it by foot, by bycicle, by car.

Here is an example of the data structure:

```
    userId  DateTime            lon         lat         speedms
1   01001   2018-05-08 17:05:21 8.551420    47.41114    1.0978790
2   01001   2018-05-08 17:05:22 8.551431    47.41115    1.5707432
3   01001   2018-05-08 17:05:23 8.551439    47.41116    1.0745824
4   01001   2018-05-08 17:05:24 8.551447    47.41116    1.1682027
5   01001   2018-05-08 17:05:25 8.551452    47.41118    1.3859502
6   01001   2018-05-08 17:05:26 8.551457    47.41118    0.9657960
7   01001   2018-05-08 17:05:27 8.551461    47.41119    1.2591893
8   01001   2018-05-08 17:05:28 8.551461    47.41121    2.0004471
9   01001   2018-05-08 17:05:29 8.551462    47.41123    2.2239989
10  01001   2018-05-08 17:05:30 8.551484    47.41124    1.6928664
11  01001   2018-05-08 17:05:31 8.551496    47.41126    *2.8167094*
12  01001   2018-05-08 17:05:32 8.551533    47.41124    *3.7848781*
13  01001   2018-05-08 17:05:33 8.551529    47.41123    0.4496923
14  01001   2018-05-08 17:05:34 8.551530    47.41125    1.2248210
15  01001   2018-05-08 17:05:35 8.551530    47.41125    0.3334079
16  01001   2018-05-08 17:05:36 8.551528    47.41126    1.3421395
17  01001   2018-05-08 17:05:37 8.551525    47.41127    0.6000021
18  01001   2018-05-08 17:05:38 8.551523    47.41128    1.1215550
19  01001   2018-05-08 17:05:39 8.551518    47.41128    1.1736288
20  01001   2018-05-08 17:05:40 8.551492    47.41132    *4.3563280*
21  01001   2018-05-08 17:05:41 8.551474    47.41135    *3.6000119*
22  01001   2018-05-08 17:05:42 8.551478    47.41135    0.3017647
23  01001   2018-05-08 17:05:43 8.551493    47.41133    2.2022842
24  01001   2018-05-08 17:05:44 8.551494    47.41133    0.5607775
25  01001   2018-05-08 17:05:45 8.551480    47.41134    1.3805747
26  01001   2018-05-08 17:05:46 8.551476    47.41131    2.9052493
27  01001   2018-05-08 17:05:47 8.551471    47.41130    1.3859500
28  01001   2018-05-08 17:05:48 8.551461    47.41130    0.8248025
29  01001   2018-05-08 17:05:49 8.551460    47.41128    2.1129303
```

This is only a subset of the data. I have over 20 million observations and no pre-classification of "trips" or whatever is made.

So, the person in the subset is walking. But there are some outliers (marked with the stars) because of the noise of the GPS device.

I can classify the GPS obverservations with the statement:

```
gps$movement <- ifelse(gps$speedms <=2.7, "walking", "not walking")
```

This is really "quick and dirty"... But it works for over 70% of the data. Now, I d'like to increase the classification success.

I think about a function, that **compares pre and post observations** and if (for example) the mean of the last 50 observations is lower than 2.7, it would classify the outlier also to **walking**.

Of course, the subset is shown only for the walking part. I have to do this also for driving, cycling.

Also the moment when a person walks first and then starts cycling is definitely challenging.

Thanks for your help!

PS: or is there even a specific r package? (I found the "trip" package, but there you need the GPS data already with a trip segmentation...)

---

My solution:

```
df <- df %>%
  mutate(rollingAvg_60 = rollapply(speedms, 60, mean, fill=NA, align='center'))
```

Comment: take a look at the froll-functions from the data.table-package.. https://rdrr.io/cran/data.table/man/froll.html

Comment: Thx Wimpel! I tried it with the zoo package, rollapply. I will have a look into the froll-functions!

Comment: Another option to try is to look at the run lengths.  It is unlikely someone is going to walk for 5 minutes, cycle for 2-3 seconds and then walk for several more minutes.  See the rle function as a starting point.